# What are the manifest.php codes for the new SugarCRM 6.2 flavors?

Tags: sugarcrm

SugarCRM 6.2 has two new editions: Corporate and Ultimate. What are the codes to put in a module's manifest.php to show you are compatible with those editions?

For 6.1 and older, it used to be:

`'acceptable_sugar_flavors' => array('CE', 'PRO', 'ENT'),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'CORP' for Corporate

'ULT' for Ultimate

Comment: John, where did CORP and ULT come from? Does SugarCRM describe the five versions anywhere?